# Pandas Bar plot for each row and grouped by columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, bar-chart

I have Pandas Dataframe of evaluation metrics for different models

```
    Model A Model B Model C
precision   0.946599    0.966482    0.990482
specificity 0.763636    0.854545    0.963636
sensitivity 0.938776    0.938776    0.857143
roc_auc 0.953061    0.953247    0.937662
acc 0.906667    0.923333    0.876667
balanced_acc    0.851206    0.89666 0.91039
f1_score    0.907219    0.925068    0.88695
```

I would like to generate a bar plot for each of the rows and grouped by columns in one plot (something like below, which I generated using google spreadsheet)

[image: barplot for each rows]

Answer (score 0):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.style.use('seaborn-white')
ax = df.plot.bar(figsize=[12, 7])
ax.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(0,1.02,1,0.2), loc="lower center", ncol=3, fontsize=16)
ax.set_xticklabels(ax.get_xticklabels(), rotation=0)
ax.tick_params(axis='both', labelsize=14)
ax.set_xlabel("X-axis", fontsize=16)
ax.set_ylabel("Y-axis", fontsize=16)
ax
```

[image]